# Binding a jquery function to an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to bind a jquery function on a click of a anchor link tag, but do not know how it can be bind, i am using ASP.net MVC with Ajax and want to show data with the help of Ajax. Please give some suggestions to bind the below function on a link click.. Thanks..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.ShowTable").click(function(e){
    var url=this.href;
    $get(url,{},function(data){
        $('#dtable').html(data)
    )};
    e.preventDefault();
});
<ul>

    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home",new {id=item.Id})">@item.Id</a><li>
    }
    </ul>
```

Comment: can you post your html code please, so we can help.

Comment: maybe just a typo in question but you are not closing ready handler. And you have a syntax error `)};` should be `});` Please consider to use your console for debugging purpose, not SO!

Comment: which version of jquery you are using

Comment: Apart from allthe answers attempting to fix your syntax errors, I suspect `$get` should be `$.get`.

Comment: @Jamiec nice catch, didn't saw it. In fact OP should really start opening his console...

Comment: where you are adding class to anchor

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( "a.ShowTable" ).bind( "click", function() {
     var url=this.href;
      $get(url,{},function(data){
         $('#dtable').html(data)
      });
       e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your fixed code: {be aware, i'm not your browser's console...}

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.ShowTable").click(function (e) {
        var url = this.href;
        $.get(url, {}, function (data) {
            $('#dtable').html(data);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: it is correct but i didn't see ShowTable class in OP Question

Comment: @Arun that's true, i guess OP knows what he is doing and not just copy/paste code from somewhere put it on his site and then ask other people to debug it. I'm just guessing, maybe i'm wrong...

Answer (score 1):

first add jQuery file on your script

then write below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","a.ShowTable,"function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url=this.href;
    $get(url,{},function(data){
        $('#dtable').html(data)
    });
 });    
});
```

Comment: document doesn't need quotes around

Comment: sometime it happen @Arun :)sorry guys

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.ShowTable").click(function(e){
    var url=$(this).attr(href);
    $.get(url,{},function(data){
        $('#dtable').html(data)
    )};
    e.preventDefault();
});

<ul>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
    <li><a href='@Url.Action("Index","Home",new {id=item.Id})' class='ShowTable'>@item.Id</a><li>
    }
    </ul>
```